# return code 999 error while executing the shell script through crontab

Tags: linux, shell, unix, error-code

I have created a shell scripts which connects to teradata and executes the given condition, lets say test.sh. i have created a wrapper script to call test.sh if there is only an input file for test.sh, wrapper.sh.
Wrapper.sh:

```
cd ${FILELOC    
COUNT=$(ls -l 1001_*.txt | wc -l)  

if [ "$COUNT" -ne 0 ]   
then      
/u/w/us/bin/test.sh.sh`       
fi
```

when i executes wrapper.sh manually, the test.sh is been called and getting executed without an error. but when i schedule it in cron it throws an error as shown below

```
EXIT ERRORCODE;
 *** Exiting BTEQ...
 *** RC (return code) = 999
```

Please help me to understand the issue

Comment: Please check the script .The first line seems to miss closing bracket, and `/u/w` line has extra backtick at the end. Also consider adding #! /bin/sh (or bash) to force the correct shell at cron.

Comment: the backtick got added while posting the script over here

Comment: #! /bin/sh is added in the script

Comment: Add '-x' to the cron job, and redirect output to a file (add a line `set -vx` at the beginning of the script

Comment: The error message seems t arrive from Terradata. What does the test.sh script do ? Does it depends on env var that are set interactilly, but are not set when running under cron ?

Answer (score 0):

- Shell script name seems to be Invalid
- Can  you  share the the content of the test.sh.sh fine so  that it will  be  easy to debug
- There might be chances that file permission are not proper. due to this it  got  failed while executing from cron scheduler